# jqwidgets radial guage styling background

Tags: css, svg, gradient, jqwidget

I am using jqwidgets. In those widgets i am using radial gauge. For that radial gauge i want to give radial background colour. i have got a code something like this for changing background color in radial gauge.

```
$('#gauge').jqxGauge({ style: { fill: '#cccccc', stroke: '#cccccc' }});
```

In the above code i have tried something like this,

```
$('#gauge').jqxGauge({ style: { fill: 'linear-gradient(to top, #000 19%, #000 41%, #232323 49%, #fff)', stroke: 'linear-gradient(to top, #000 19%, #000 41%, #232323 49%, #fff)' }});
```

But this isnt working. Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think CSS gradients work as SVG fills.

So you will need to define your gradients in an SVG you embed in the page.  Then you can reference them for your gauge.

So, for instance, the equivalent SVG gradient definition for your fill one would be:

```
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gaugefill" x1="0" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0">
            <stop offset="19%" stop-color="#000"/>
            <stop offset="41%" stop-color="#000"/>
            <stop offset="49%" stop-color="#232323"/>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#fff"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Put this in your page somewhere.  Then you should be able to apply it to your guage with:

```
$('#gauge').jqxGauge({ style: { fill: 'url(#gaugefill)', stroke: '#ccccc` }});
```

I'll leave the stroke one for you to do.

PS. Disclaimer: I have not used these widgets, so this is an educated guess only.